# Turn display of marker tooltips on/off in layer control in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, markers, tooltip

I want to add tooltip which will show magnitude for each earthquake epicenter and was able to make it but I have a problem that with many epicenters in one area tooltips are overlapped.

My question is can I first hide tooltips (magnitudes) and then on control when clicked to show them?

This is my code that shows epicenters, and at the end you will see that I have added .bindTooltip.

```
var earthquakes = L.geoJson([], {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) { 
            var props = feature.properties;
            
        },
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            var color,
                mag,
                radius,
                weight;
                mag = feature.properties.mag;
                label = String(mag);
            if (mag === null) {
                color = '#FF0000';
                radius = 2;
                weight = 1;
            } else {
                color = '#FF0000';
                radius = 2 * Math.max(mag, 1);
                weight = 1;
            }
            if (feature.properties.type === 'quarry blast') {
                color = '#FF00FF';
            }
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                color: color,
                radius: radius,
                weight: weight
            }).bindTooltip(label, {
                permanent: true, 
                direction: 'center',
                opacity: 0.65,
                className: 'pointlabel' 
            }).openTooltip();
        }
    }).addTo(map);
```

At the beginning of code I have below code for controls where I can switch map and also show lines (earth faults), so can I somehow by using overlays control be able to bintooltip when checked and unbindtooltip when unchecked?

```
var Faults = new L.LayerGroup();
var Tooltip = new L.LayerGroup();
var Base = {
  "Arcgis map": Arcmap,
  "Google terrain": googlemap
};
var overlays = {
  "Faults": Faults,
  "Tooltip": Tooltip
};

L.control.layers(Base, overlays, {collapsed:false}).addTo(map);
```

In layer control I would like to have checkbox called tooltip so when checked it show tooltip and when unchecked hide it, see image below:

[image]

Here is complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/Tkalac/f5mqo6Lj/1/#&togetherjs=9KtCAh7Unw

Comment: In layer control I would like to have checkbox called tooltip so when checked it show tooltip and when unchecked hide it.
Please check image https://i.ibb.co/D18jVZy/control.jpg

Comment: But tooltips are dependant on Faults layer. What if Faults layer is not checked and Tooltips is checked?

Comment: Tooltips are not dependant of Faults layer.
If I check faults it shows faults, when unchecked it hide it.
Tooltip check should show tooltip and when unchecked to hide them.

Each work for it self which I did test and instead of tooltip I added layer with some polygon and when checked tooltip polygon show, when unchecked polygon disaper so faults and tool tip as check options are not linked to each other.

Comment: Please check example what happen when faults is checked, what happen when Tooltip is checked (I created few lines for example) and what happen when both are checked.
They are not linked to each other.
https://i.ibb.co/G5RMtS6/example.jpg

Comment: I admit I'm completely lost now. In code I see layer `earthquakes` with circle markers, then there is layer `Faults` with no contents, and on the picture there are circle markers (probablay layer `earthquakes`, which I don't see added to the layer control) and some lines, which are probably coming from layer `Faults`. Please edit your question, add more code if necessary and try to explain what is what and step by step what should happen.

Comment: Sorry for that but code is a bit long and I wanted to show only relevant parts. Also Html has links to other js and css files which is not easy for me to paste here. 
But please check https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Ove8Bz7Bwf as I copy/paste code there .
You can see that in line 75 in js file I added bindtooltip that tooltip is binded to each circle marker.
Under that from line 85 to 96 is Layer control where for test I placed  var Tooltip = new L.LayerGroup();.
But layer control "Tooltip" checkmark should unbind tooltip from circle markers.
So that check mark should

Comment: If still unclear what I want to achieve this exactly shows what should happen when Tooltip in layercontrol is checked and unchecked.

https://i.ibb.co/qpShFmt/tooltip.jpg

Comment: That's what I thought you want to achieve, but it's still not completely clear. If this layer with circles and tooltips is `earthquakes`, is it shown all the time and you cannot switch it of in layer control? You just want to switch on/off its tooltips?

Comment: If I try to view your JSFiddle, it's empty.

Comment: Please use this one https://jsfiddle.net/Tkalac/f5mqo6Lj/1/#&togetherjs=9KtCAh7Unw.

Red circles are earthquake epicenters. Each red circle has bindtooltip which is earthquake magnitude so I need to hide or unhide based on Control Layer check/uncheck option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group layer `Tooltip` can be used not to actually display tooltips, bust just as a switch in layer control to trigger tooltips display on/off.

When layer `Tooltip` is selected in the control, it fires layer event `add`. In event processing function markers from `earthquakesEMSC` are iterated and tooltips made permanent. When layer `Tooltip` is deselected in the control,  it fires layer event `remove`. In event processing function markers from `earthquakesEMSC` are iterated and tooltips made not permanent.

Logic of the code below is that initially tooltips are not displayed.

```
var earthquakesEMSC = L.geoJson([], {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) { 
    var props = feature.properties;

    var datum = props.time,
    split = datum.split('T');
    var vrijeme = split[1],
    split2 = split[1].split('.'); 
    layer.bindPopup('Date: ' + split[0] + '</br>' + 'Time: ' + split2[0] + '</br>' + 'Type: ' + props.magtype + '</br>' + 'Mag: ' + props.mag + '</br>' + 'Depth: ' + props.depth + ' km' + '</br>' + 'Station: ' + props.auth + '</br>' +'source: ' + props.source_catalog);
  },
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    label = String(feature.properties.mag) 
    var color,
      mag,
      radius,
      weight;
      mag = feature.properties.mag;
      label = String(mag);
    if (mag === null) {
      color = '#FF0000';
      radius = 2;
      weight = 1;
    } else {
      color = '#FF0000';
      radius = 2 * Math.max(mag, 1);
      weight = 1;
    }
    if (feature.properties.type === 'quarry blast') {
      color = '#FF00FF';
    }
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      color: color,
      radius: radius,
      weight: weight
    }).bindTooltip(label, {
      direction: 'center',
      opacity: 0.5,
      className: 'pointlabel'
    });
  }
}).addTo(map);

var Tooltip = new L.LayerGroup();

Tooltip.on('add', function() {
  earthquakesEMSC.eachLayer(function(marker) {
    var tooltip = marker.getTooltip();
    marker.unbindTooltip();
    tooltip.options.permanent = true;
    marker.bindTooltip(tooltip);
  });
});
Tooltip.on('remove', function() {
  earthquakesEMSC.eachLayer(function(marker) {
    var tooltip = marker.getTooltip();
    marker.unbindTooltip();
    tooltip.options.permanent = false;
    marker.bindTooltip(tooltip);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you this works fine.
There is one thing I had to change as tooltips showed when map is loaded which I didn't want (only show/hide via controls) so I changed permanent from true to false ,  bindTooltip(label, { permanent: false,.